# Letting the user add values into the database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm running a database in SQL2012 and using Visual Studio2012 C# to build a software that interacts with the database, and I've been trying to add a button that interacts with a textbox or something similar that lets the user add/edit rows in the database.

Code:

```
try
            {

                string conString = "Data Source=MIRANDA-PC;Initial Catalog=Futebol do Rosa;Integrated Security=True";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
                string selectSql = "Update Players$ SET Player Name='" + textBox3.Text + "' WHERE Player ID= 1";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSql, con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("The values have been UPDATED");
            }
            catch{
                MessageBox.Show("not so fast ***, error found in your ******** code");
            }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Could you provide the code?

Comment: This is the code I've tried, but I know it's completely wrong because to add I wanted it to generate automatic ID's and this is kind of me just trying to edit the values, which completely failed
http://pastebin.com/EAxSGdCY

Comment: Please add *relevant code* to the question rather than an external link along with what's wrong, failing or missing. That link might not last as long as this question, so this question won't be useful in future if the link changes.

Comment: But that's the only code I've written in regards to this problem and that link never expires

Comment: Apart from the silly error comment, you haven't said what happens when you run this code. Instead of the silly comment, you could try catch (Exception exc) { MessageBox.Show(exc.Message + "/" + exc.StackTrace);}

Answer (score 0):

The code in your link isn't even safe.

- Your SqlConnction and SqlCommand will not dispose
- The end user can use SQL Injection

Throw your SqlConnection and SqlCommand in an using statement.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
{
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("your query here", con))
   {
       con.Open(); 
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

Add parameters to your SqlCommand to avoid SqlInjection

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", value);
```

Create your own class for database interaction and don't put everything in one class or form.

If you let us know what the error is, we can help you more.
Also a good thing is to google your error first.

Comment: On a slightly funny note, googling programing related questions will bring you back to `stackoverflow`, ha-ha, ha-ha (weak laughter)...

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the safety issues (inline SQL is bad. Very bad.) Your update has some fundamental errors. Try:

```
string selectSql = "Update Players SET Players.Name='" + textBox3.Text + 
                   "' WHERE Players.ID= 1";
```

Your table columns need to be associated to the table with a `.` and the table name has to be the same as the one you are updating. I am going on the assumption here that your table name is `Players`

Comment: On top of inline SQL being unsafe it is also hard to debug.

Comment: Do you know how I make the Players.ID value changeable? I've tried numericUpanddown and it didn't work, then I tried using a textbox but it said the value was a string and I need it to be a float, didn't find any conversion statement though

Comment: What type is Players.ID? If it is generated by the database it should be an `int` (I think).

Comment: It's a float, because it's a field we created ourselves

Comment: You should be able to just use an `update` though I am not entirely sure as I don't usually use `float` in my databases. I would caution against using `float` types for an ID field. They are imprecise.

Comment: Do you know how I can "Parse" the String value to a float?

Comment: use `CONVERT(FLOAT, yourstring)`